# How to get rid of long initialization without losing flexibililty

Tags: c++, oop, io

Consider this example

```
Gabi::Herbs::Filesystem::FileReader filereader
    {
    Gabi::Herbs::Filesystem::FileIn
        {Gabi::Herbs::Filesystem::Path(GABI_HERBS_STR("herbs/textio/test_utf8.txt")),0}
        ,0
    };
Gabi::Herbs::IO::ReaderBuffering reader(filereader,128);
Gabi::Herbs::TextIO::Decoder decoder(reader,Gabi::Herbs::TextIO::ConverterUTF8::factory);
```

It is C++ but it could be any language with support for OOP. So

1. Use a Path abstraction to distinguish a file path from a general string
2. Create a random access file. This does not move any file pointer
3. Read the file using a FileReader [FileIn has been copy constructed through reference counting]. The reader will start zero bytes from begin of file.
4. Since it is a text file, it is good to use buffered I/O. This reduces the number of syscalls needed. In this case, it fetches 128 bytes at each call.
5. A text file may be coded in many different ways. Create a decoder that tries to decode the file.

How can I create a wrapper in this case so I do not need to create three objects, and two temporary objects? It is possible to use merge classes, but then some flexibility is lost.

Comment: `using Gabi::Herbs::Filesystem; using Gabi::Herbs::IO;` strictly **in local scope** could be the first step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe create a new class, like this:

```
class FileReaderDecoder
{
    Gabi::Herbs::Filesystem::FileReader filereader;
    Gabi::Herbs::IO::ReaderBuffering reader;
    Gabi::Herbs::TextIO::Decoder decoder;

public:
    FileReaderDecoder(std::string file_name)
    {/*Initialize the three member variables like you did in your own code*/}

    //Add accessor functions here to get the data from the decoded file, e.g.:
    std::string GetData(int start, int size);
}
```

Then the call reduces to, e.g.

```
FileReaderDecoder file_rd_dec("herbs/textio/test_utf8.txt");
file_rd_dec.GetData(0, 16);
```

Comment: This doesn't need a class at all, here a simple function would do.

Comment: To maintain flexibility, you could pass additional arguments to the constructor to specify how the file should be decoded (ASCII, UTF8, etc).